# Finding numbers on a curve whos sum equals x.

Tags: curves, neural-networks

I'm designing a program that generates neural networks. And I'm trying to create a function that would tell me how many neurons to put in the hidden layers.

I need a function that basically plots "Points" on a curve whos sum equals some number.

For example with this data-set:

```
Input neurons: 784
Output neurons: 10
Neurons in layers: 89 // sqrt(inputs * outputs);
Hidden Layers: 2 //ceil(log10(Neurons in layers));
```

For this data set I would want 2 number numbers between 784 and 10 who's sum equals 89 where p1 > p2

I have no idea that math for that, nor even how to ask the question to google.

Most of the guides for neural networks, and papers just have "Choose an arbitrary number" or just use "x".

Comment: Why not just take $45, 44$?

Comment: @MeesdeVries I was hoping to get some numbers that made the shrink from upper to lower curve nicely.